# Displaying lake contours as depth rather than elevation

Tags: arcgis-pro, contour, 3d-map

I have a set of contour lines for Lake Erie with negative Z-values. I am happy with how they display in 3d but need them subsurface to show depth rather than elevation. The tallest portion in cyan should be the deepest portion of the lake.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you can use a negative vertical exaggeration, or if there's a flag to define how the Z values are interpreted.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the attribute table of these data?  Specifically show the values you are claiming are depths below the datum?

Comment: Is there a vertical coordinate system assigned to the layer? If so, what is it?

Comment: @GBG I added the attribute Table!

Comment: And which of those attributes are you using to render your graphic?  On the right side of your display I can see the symbol classes but not the values.  Can you post a clear shot of that?